# for loop with standard output

Tags: for-loop, unix

I want to run **two** scripts (gunzip and fastx_collapser) for multiple input files. The output from gunzip should be input to fastx_collapser. How do I do this in a loop function?

My try:

```
for f in *.gz    gunzip -c "$f"  | fastx_collapser -Q33 -z -o  "${f%}.coll.gz"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `do` and a `done` (and some semicolons if you insist on a single line):

```
for f in *.gz
do
    gunzip -c "$f" | fastx_collapser -Q33 -z -o "${f%}.coll.gz"
done
```

or:

```
for f in *.gz; do gunzip -c "$f" | fastx_collapser -Q33 -z -o "${f%}.coll.gz"; done
```